# DNS: How to map domain to IP:PORT, not just IP?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have 2 Web Sites and 1 Web Application (WCF Service). I also have one domain, managed by opensrs.net.

I didn't have any problems mapping the sites to the domain, via DNS -> CNAME.

```
*.abcd.com -> abcd.host.com
play.abcd.com -> abcd.otherhost.com
```

However, I'm having problems mapping the Web Application.

```
api.abcd.com -> abcd.otherhost.com:8081
```

I searched the net, and someone suggested that I should use DNS -> SRV.

```
api.abcd.com -> Priority: 1
                Weight: 1
                Port: 8081
                Host: abcd.otherhost.com
```

Still didn't work.

Comment: There is no commonly used HTTP client that uses SRV records for locating a site.  There is no way to do this via DNS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do this via DNS in a reliable way as the use of SRV records for HTTP is not widespread.

The normal way to do this is to use a reverse proxy to proxy requests to the relevant ports.

Answer (score -1):

## This isn't actually too difficult.

### How to set up

1. Use the **DNS** for what is supposed to do.

   - Set up the DNS and CNAME records so all desired names resolve to the correct host.
2. Set up **Virtual Host** configs (if you run Apache)

   - Use the same hostname as in the DNS record and any desired (available) port number.
   - Configure the directory for each **Virtual Host**. Make sure directories exist and are accesible by Apache.
3. Enable your **Virtual Host** configuration files, then restart Apache to load the changes.

### Why this works

If this was done correctly, then Apache will direct traffic to/from the right port number by matching hostname in **Virtual Host** config with the value of the **server hostname** field in each **HTTP request header**.

### What about ports NOT configured/managed by Apache?

This can be achieved either by setting up a separate Proxy server or by enabling and configuring Apache proxy functionality and virtual hostname configs.